# I came across a reflect invocation target exeption in processing and can't find what is causing it

Tags: processing

I was remaking a platformer after I closed it without saving my code and came across the error. I don't know how the error occurred and am completely lost.
Here's the code below(sorry for any incomplete code):

```java
PImage saw = loadImage("saw.png");
game run = new game();
void setup(){
   size(1000, 1000);
}
void draw(){
  run.saw(100, 100);
}
class game{
  boolean dead;
  int ballX;
  int ballY;
  int sawRotate;
  game(){
    dead = false;
    ballX = 100;
    ballY = 50;
    sawRotate = 1;
  }
  void ball(){

  }
  void saw(int x, int y){
    pushMatrix();
    rotate(sawRotate);
    translate(x, y);
    image(saw, 100, -100, 500, 500);
    popMatrix();
  }
  void platform(){

  }
}
```

Comment: You need to at least tell us which line the exception occurred at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Processing functions until after the `setup()` function has been called. This line happens before that:

```
PImage saw = loadImage("saw.png");
```

You need to move the call to `loadImage()` to be inside the `setup()` function:

```
PImage saw;
void setup(){
   size(1000, 1000);
   saw = loadImage("saw.png");
}
```

Comment: Thanks the exception no longer occurs, although a few more bugs popped up that easily fixed.